# How can I add a template in the isolated shell

Tags: visual-studio, shell, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I'm working with Microsoft Visual Studio isolated Shell (2015).
I want to add my own created template.

What I already did:

1. I created a new isolated shell project (File -> New Project -> Other Project Types -> Extensibility -> Visual Studio isolated Shell)

2. I created a Template as a .zip-file (File -> New Project -> Visaul C# -> C# Project Template -> Add Items (files and folder) - > Export Template

3. This .zip-file I added to my isolated shell (.vsixmanifest -> Assets -> New)

If I debugg my project, i can't see my project in the isolated shell only the blank solution.

How can I make my template visible??

Thank you in advance